# evaluation of a definite integral involving inverse hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, approximation

The following integral appears during the analysis of statistical mechanical models.

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi /2}{\operatorname{arctanh} \left[ {\sqrt {1 - \sin (x)\sin (x){a^2}} } \right]dx} $$

Is there a closed form solution for the integral?

Comment: Yes. inverse tan hyperbolic function was meant., as mentioned by you.The answer appears to be in terms of Meijer G function and I feel that some simpler result may emerge.

Comment: Could you tell where/how you saw Meijer G function ?

Comment: Thanks for the interesting comment. If the inverse tan hyperbolic function of this question  is written using the log functions,the Meijer G function arises as was mentioned on 2 August 2020 by you, for a related question posed by me. The integral given in this question itself was arrived at after transforming the log function into inverse tan hyperbolic function, as you can immediately notice.The integral given in this question seems easier to handle.

Comment: How, at my age, do you want me to remember ? (joke). Cheers :-)

Comment: In fact,I am amazed at your expertise in diverse branches of mathematics. Hence I am fairly confident that evaluation of this integral will be within your reach!

Comment: I am not a mathematician

Comment: If $0<a<1$ then: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-a^2 \sin ^2(x)}\right) \, dx=-\frac{1}{16} \left(a^2 \pi \right)-\frac{9 a^4 \pi }{512}-\frac{25 a^6 \pi
   }{3072}+\pi  \log (2)-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log (a)+..+$

Comment: I edited for the integral. If this looks like a valid answer, may be, you could accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$I(b)=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-b \sin ^2(x)}\right)\,dx$$
$$I'(b)=-\frac 1{2b}\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-b \sin ^2(x)}}=-\frac{K\left(\frac{b}{b-1}\right)}{2 b\sqrt{1-b}}$$ and $I(1)=2 C$. So
$$I(a^2)=2C+\frac 12 \int_{a^2}^1\frac{1}{ b\sqrt{1-b}}K\left(\frac{b}{b-1}\right)\,db$$

You could use the series
$$I'(b)=\frac{\pi }{4 b}+ \pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\alpha_n}{2^{\beta_n}} b^n $$

The $\alpha_n$ correspond to sequence $A038534$ in $OEIS$ and the $\beta_n$ form the sequence
$$\{4,8,10,16,18,22,24,32,34,38,40,46,48,52,54,64,66,70,72,78,80,84,86
   ,94,96,100,\cdots\}$$

Integrating termwise leads to more than decent approximations.

$$J=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-a^2 \sin ^2(x)}\right)\,dx=2C-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log (a)+\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\alpha_n}{2^{\beta_n}\,(n+1)}(1-a^{2(n+1)})$$

**Edit**

Reworking
$$J=\frac 12 \int_{a^2}^1\frac{1}{ b\sqrt{1-b}}K\left(\frac{b}{b-1}\right)\,db$$

let $b=\sin^2(t)$ to make
$$J=\int_{\sin ^{-1}(a)}^{\frac \pi 2} \csc (t) \,K\left(-\tan ^2(t)\right)\,dt$$

Using
$$K\left(-z^2\right)=\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac {\alpha_n}{2^{\gamma_n}}\, z^{2n} $$ the $\gamma_n$ forming the sequence
$$\{1,3,7,9,15,17,21,23,31,33,37,39,45,47,51,53,63,65,69,71,77,79,8
   3,85,93,\cdots\}$$
$$J=-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log \left(\tan \left(\frac{\sin
   ^{-1}(a)}{2} \right)\right)+$$ $$\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac {\alpha_n}{2^{\gamma_n}}\,2^{2 n-1} \left(B_1(n,1-2 n)-B_{\tan ^2\left(\frac{\sin
   ^{-1}(a)}{2} \right)}(n,1-2 n)\right)$$

Comment: excellent and thanks;  If b equals zero or 1, will the answer be still valid?

Comment: thanks for your efforts. Will look into both answers. If any queries persist,I will again post.

Answer (score 1):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\left(0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(b\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\sqrt{1-b\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)},$$

where here the real inverse hyperbolic tangent is defined by

$$\operatorname{artanh}{\left(x\right)}:=\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}=\frac12\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)};~~~\small{x\in\left(-1,1\right)}.$$

Consider the following [specific value](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/08/06/01/02/08/0001/) for the generalized hypergeometric function $_3F_2$:

$${_3F_2}{\left(1,1,\frac32;2,2;z\right)}=-\frac{4}{z}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-z}}{2}\right)};~~~\small{z\in(-\infty,1]}.$$

We can use this fact to rewrite the most complicated part of the integrand of $\mathcal{I}$ as a hypergeometric function.

---

For any $b\in\left(0,1\right]$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(b\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\sqrt{1-b\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\sqrt{1-bx^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[\theta=\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\sqrt{1-bt}\right)}}{2\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}};~~~\small{\left[x=\sqrt{t}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-bt}}{1-\sqrt{1-bt}}\right)}}{4\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{(1+\sqrt{1-bt})^{2}}{bt}\right)}}{4\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-bt}\right)}-\ln{\left(bt\right)}}{4\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-bt}\right)}-2\ln{\left(2\right)}+2\ln{\left(2\right)}-\ln{\left(b\right)}-\ln{\left(t\right)}}{4\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-bt}}{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{b}{4}\right)}-\ln{\left(t\right)}}{4\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{b}{4}\right)}}{4\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(t\right)}}{4\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-bt}}{2}\right)}}{2\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(2\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(b\right)}+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-bt}}{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(2\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(b\right)}-\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{bt}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\left[-\frac{4}{bt}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-bt}}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(2\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(b\right)}-\frac{b}{8}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{1/2}\left(1-t\right)^{-1/2}\,{_3F_2}{\left(1,1,\frac32;2,2;bt\right)}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(2\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(b\right)}-\frac{b}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac32,\frac12\right)}\,{_4F_3}{\left(1,1,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2;b\right)}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(2\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(b\right)}-\frac{\pi}{16}b\,{_4F_3}{\left(1,1,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2;b\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where the final integration comes from Euler's [integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Euler%27s_integral_transform) for higher-order hypergeometric functions:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{d-1}\left(1-t\right)^{r-d-1}\,{_3F_2}{\left(a,b,c;p,q;zt\right)}=\operatorname{B}{\left(d,r-d\right)}\,{_4F_3}{\left(a,b,c,d;p,q,r;z\right)};~~~\small{0<d<r}.$$

---

Comment: the most complete and exact answer. Is the hypergeometric function given here is easier to handle than Meijer G function,alluded to earlier, for a similar integral?

Comment: @sangara In my experience, yes.

Comment: very important and impressive  result; the online evaluation of 2F1(a,b,c;z) is available in a straightforward manner; does a similar method exist for 4F3(a,b,c,d,p,q,r;z)?Which is the best source for information on these higher order hypergeometric functions?For b=1, what will be the value of 4F3, given in the final step?

Answer (score 0):

Given:
$$I(a)=\int\limits_0^{\pi /2}{\operatorname{arctanh} ( {\sqrt {1 - a^2\sin^2 x}})  \;dx}$$

The inverse hyperbolic tangent is given by

$$\operatorname{arctanh}z=\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$

So we can after some transformations present the integrand in the form

$$\ln(1+\sqrt {1 - a^2\sin^2 x})-\ln a -\ln \sin x $$

Using well known result

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi /2}\ln \sin x\;dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2$$

we get after integrating:

$$I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\frac{2}{a}+\int\limits_0^{\pi /2}\ln(1+\sqrt {1 - a^2\sin^2 x})\;dx$$

We can already get useful information from this result.

Asymptotic behavior of $I(a)$ as $a$ tends to zero:

$$I(a)\to \frac{\pi}{2}\ln\frac{2}{a}$$

At $a=1$ we get:

$$I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2+\int\limits_0^{\pi /2}\ln(1+\cos x)\;dx=2G$$

where $G$ is  Catalan's constant.

Well known result

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi /2}\ln(1+\cos x)\;dx=2G-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2$$

is used.

For values around $a=\frac{1}{2}$ simply expand $I(a)$ in Taylor's series about $a$ as given by Mariusz Iwaniuk.

Some of the first terms are already giving an excellent accuracy.

Comment: Thanks .This solution is useful in terms of the accuracy with the numerical integration answer. However, the given integral itself was arrived at by re-writing the log function, in terms of tan hyperbolic, with the hope that new insights may emerge . The exact solution of the integral is in terms of Meijer G function as was pointed out earlier in another post on 2 August 2020.

Comment: @sangara Why do you need Meijer G function?  Better understand physics?

Comment: Thanks for your interesting comment. Meijer G function does give the location of the singularity in the second derivative, as is well known in the two-dimensional  lattice models. My objective is to deduce a simpler function for the integral even if not very accurate,numerically.